# I'm getting an indentation error when i specify the time (hour and minutes)

Tags: python

i'm having this error with my code. Basically what i'm trying to do is to play a song a specific time. It's working when the hour between a range of hours however when i specify the hour and minute it's giving me an indentation error:

THIS ONE IS WORKING:

```
import time 
import datetime
import os, random
import webbrowser


now = datetime.datetime.now()
now.hour

basedirC = "C:\\Users\Random"
file = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(basedirC) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basedirC, x))])

if 18 < now.hour < 24 :
    print ("It's evening")
    webbrowser.open(os.path.join(basedirC, file))
   
else: 
    print (" It's not evening")
```

THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING IT WRONG:

```
import time 
import datetime
import os, random
import webbrowser


now = datetime.datetime.now()
now.hour
now.minute

basedirC = "C:\\Users\Random"
file = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(basedirC) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basedirC, x))])

if now.hour = 22 and now.minute = 12 :
    print ("It's evening")
    webbrowser.open(os.path.join(basedirC, file))
   
else: 
    print (" It's not evening")
```

I'm getting: indentation errors on the print function and the  webbrowser.open funtion. any clue?

Comment: Yeah, a little clue is the fact that you're calling `now.hour` and `now.minute` without doing anything to those variables. What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the `if` statment you need to use `==` not `=`, the equal symbol is reserved for assignment.

Comment: `=` is assignment, but you want the `==` comparitor in those if statement.s

Comment: When posting a problem like this, include the full traceback message so we see the failing line easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is an [assignment staement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) which can't be used in a larger expression. Lately, the `:=` [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) has been added so that you can write things like that.

However, what you really wanted was the `==` equality [comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

```
import time 
import datetime
import os, random
import webbrowser


now = datetime.datetime.now()
# has no effect...
#now.hour
#now.minute

basedirC = "C:\\Users\Random"
file = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(basedirC) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basedirC, x))])

if now.hour == 22 and now.minute == 12 :
    print ("It's evening")
    webbrowser.open(os.path.join(basedirC, file))
   
else: 
    print (" It's not evening")
```

But that's probably not quite what you want either... this if only runs for 1 minute a day at 22:12. If its 22:13, it won't think its evening. If you want your code to run at any time after 22:12, then you could take the time of day component from the datetime object and compare it to a given time:

```
if now.time() >= dt.time(22,21):
    ...
```